# Get index of database iteration on ruby

Tags: ruby, gdbm

I'm trying to iterate through database file with gdbm, create objects with values I get and assign them to an array. The problem is I can't seem to get index of iteration and I need it for my array. Here is the code:

```
bots_directory = "../data/bots.db"

bots = Array.new

GDBM.new(bots_directory).each_pair.with_index do |nickname, password, index|
   bots[index] = Bot.new(nickname, password)
end
```

Error I get:

```
`[]=': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
```

Also, will database file close after the block is executed?

Comment: This is a simple misunderstanding of how the arguments are yielded to the block and how parallel assignment works. your code will yield `[[key,value],index]` this means that nickname is now `[key,value]`, password is `index`, and index is nil. To split out key value you need to wrap nickname and password in parentheses to have them split it then becomes `nickname,password = [key,value]` and `index = index`.But @spickermann has suggested far better ways to accomplish this such as map. For a quick understanding try this in irb `a,b,c = [["k","v"],1]` then try `(a,b),c = [["k","v"],1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `each_with_index` instead of `each_pair.with_index`:

```
bots_directory = "../data/bots.db"
bots = []

GDBM.new(bots_directory).each_with_index do |(nickname, password), index|
  bots[index] = Bot.new(nickname, password)
end
```

Or even simpler, since the index starts from `0` and increases by `1` anyway:

```
bots_directory = "../data/bots.db"
bots = []

GDBM.new(bots_directory).each_pair do |nickname, password|
  bots << Bot.new(nickname, password)
end
```

Perhaps `map` is also an option?

```
bots_directory = "../data/bots.db"

bots = GDBM.new(bots_directory).map do |nickname, password|
  Bot.new(nickname, password)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use `map`

Comment: Excellent answer although explaining why this doesn't work (yielded arguments and parallel assignment) would probably be a beneficial addition.